# Unable to click submit button using selenium- Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I've created a small script to go to reddit login page enter username and password. My last step is to click the Log In button but my xpath is unable to find it and click the button. I've tried various different ways but none seem to be working.

Below is what i've tried

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='submit']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='submit']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.className("submitButton")).click();
```

Below is what chrome inspect gives

```
 <button class="AnimatedForm__submitButton m-full-width" type="submit">     
            Log In        
      </button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `WebDriverWait()` wait for `elementToBeClickable()` and following `xpath`.

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[contains(.,'Log In')]"))).click();
```

OR

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@class='AnimatedForm__submitButton m-full-width' and @type='submit']"))).click();
```